# I am trying to plot a 5*2 plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a set of graphs in python using the code as below.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(521)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(s0, lags=40, ax=ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(522)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(s0, lags=40, ax=ax2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(523)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(s1, lags=40, ax=ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(524)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(s1, lags=40, ax=ax2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(525)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(s2, lags=40, ax=ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(526)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(s2, lags=40, ax=ax2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(527)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(s3, lags=40, ax=ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(528)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(s3, lags=40, ax=ax2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(529)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_acf(s4, lags=40, ax=ax1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(5210)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(s4, lags=40, ax=ax4)
```

There is a error in the line where i have plotted 10th subplot and the 10th subplot is not getting displayed in output.
The code is as follows

```
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(5210)
fig = sm.graphics.tsa.plot_pacf(s4, lags=40, ax=ax4)
```

and the error message is as follows

**Integer subplot specification must be a three digit number.  Not 4**

I think the problem is with (5210).The first two digit specify the rows and columns of graphs i.e 52 means 5 columns and 2 rows, a total of 10 graphs and the 3rd digit refers to the placement number i>e 1,2,3,...10. things work fine upto (529) but shows a error in (5210).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`5210` gives an error because it naively expects a 3-digit integer. The issue is that it cannot parse whether you mean *"5 rows, 2 columns, 10th plot"* or *"5 rows, 21 columns, 0th plot"*, etc.

You can get around this by separating the numbers with commas and using each as a separate agrument. That is:

```
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(5, 2, 10)
```